# Why try catch is not working in this case?

Tags: angular

I  have an Angular App with a login service like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
       ....
     socialLogin(provider: SocialLoginProvider) {
          gapi.auth2
                .getAuthInstance()
                .signIn()
                .then(() => {
                    this.googleAuthLoginStatusChangeCallback(
                        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()
                    );
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Here is executed');
                    throw new Error('Error');
                });
     }
}
```

then my `login.component.ts` using this service:

```
socialLogin(provider: SocialLoginProvider) {
   try {
         this.loginService.socialLogin(provider);
   } catch(err) {
      console.log('This not Execute'); // this line does not execute;
   }
}
```

When I get an error on the `.catch()` of the promise, I can see an error message coming from the gapi sdk on the console and my custom log message `Here is executed`, meaning that my error is being throwed, but it´s not being handled by the `try/catch` block of the component. Is this the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is due to the `try {} catch(err) {}` being a synchronous operation, while your `.then().catch()` is designed to be asynchronous.

In the case of your `try catch`, the error may occur after the code is executed, therefore is not detected.

Comment: this makes total sense. I cannot find a way to handle this on the component itself and not on the service.

Comment: this is correct. the execution will have passed the `catch` branch already, unless it would throw an error immediately - which will never happen, due to the promise.

Comment: You could switch from `Promises` to `Observables` to set the logic in the service and catch your error in your component using the `.subscribe(data => dataStuff, error => errorStuff, () => onCompleteStuff)`

Comment: @Askirkela it would still be a `Promise`... which nevertheless can be observed.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes, but I don't know if you can set the `catch` logic of a Promise anywhere other than right after the `then` logic. Which you can do with Observables. But I'm biaised because I came to like the Observables...

Comment: this at least works the other way around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303033/how-to-return-a-promise-from-subscribe-in-angular-5 ...one just cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous execution, because it will result in race conditions alike the one here.